# CDataTable (Core UI React) prop onPageChange trigger 2 times

Tags: reactjs, core-ui

I am new in React and Core ui.
My problem is when I try to prop onPageChange CDataTable from Core UI React, it always trigger 2 times.
So if I want to hit endpoint get data based on selected page when on page change, the data will be wrong.
This is my example of CDataTable core ui

```
<CDataTable
  items={this.state.consultant}
  fields={fields}
  itemsPerPage={10}
  pagination
  onPageChange={() => console.log('Hello')}
  loading={true}
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm solve it with check like

```
const onPageChange = nextPage => {
   if (nextPage != currentPage) {
     // doSomeThing 
   }
}
```

of corse you need to store `currentPage` in your state. Due to source of CDataTable, they use React useState for default behavior.

There is still triggers 2 times, but do payload once.

Also you can use CDataTable and CPagination separately, in that case `onPageChange` triggers only once.